# Is it relevant to use "switches" buttons in non-mobile app?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, buttons

I want to use this kind of UI elements in my web app.

[image]

They look nice and they don't lake a lot of place in the layout. 
I don't see them often beside mobile app, is it a good idea to use them for every web application ?

By the way, does a specific name exists for these elements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do look nice, but you have to ask how well they fit with an app that is designed to be operated by mouse clicks rather than a touchscreen.

In an app you simply slide the switch with your finger. It's better than a checkbox because it requires you to press and slide, rather than just tap (as you would with a check box), which can happen accidentally.

I'd say for the average web app you're better going with something like a standard checkbox or a toggle button. They all signify a true/false at the end of the day.

Comment: These switches usually (Android and iOS) do not require you to press and slide. A tap is enough to change the value.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I still think having to click and then slide it using a mouse seems slightly cumbersome. I guess you have to decide what is best for your own application.

Comment: I, as a user, find them slightly difficult to operate when I use a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use an element just because you find it nice. It's sort of weird to build a web app around a design element. You have to define clearly what your web app is, what it does and then see what you really need.

However, I'll answer to **"is it a good idea to use them for every web application ?"**

No. It's not a good idea to use them for every web application since every project is different. You may or may not have to use it. Actually, those elements are like radio buttons (with two choices). So I guess you could use it this way. Even if we're used to see it on mobile app, there is a lots of ways to implement it on a desktop web app.